# Page reload onChange on type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to console.log the input value inside Input but every time i type something the page reloads. Console show no errors.

```
const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState("");
  const textHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredText(event.target.value);
  };
  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const textData = {
      text: enteredText,
    };
    console.log(textData);
  };
  return (
    <Post onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <TopPost>
        <ProfilePicture></ProfilePicture>
        <Input
          placeholder="What's happening?"
          required
          onChange={textHandler}
        />
      </TopPost>
      <BottomPost>
        <Button type="submit">Post</Button>
      </BottomPost>
    </Post>
```

Comment: try `const textHandler = () => event => {` instead

Comment: @assembler It worked! Now when i submit something only the first letter is saved and displayed in console log

Comment: Try putting event.preventDefault() inside textHandler().